# How to use publicRuntimeConfig on nuxt plugins

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I create vue socket io plugins @/plugins/socket-io.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

Vue.use(
  new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: process.env.SOCKET_IO_CONNECTION,
  })
)
```

how to change that to use publicRuntimeConfig

my nuxt.config.js

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    peerServerHost: process.env.PEER_SERVER_HOST,
    peerServerPort: process.env.PEER_SERVER_PORT,
    peerServerPath: process.env.PEER_SERVER_PATH,
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    signalServerKey: process.env.SIGNAL_SERVER_KEY,
    signalServerCert: process.env.SIGNAL_SERVER_CERT,
    socketIOConnection: process.env.SOCKET_IO_CONNECTION,
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the way,

move `socketIOConnection` to publicRuntimeConfig

then in @/plugins/socket-io.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

export default function ({ $config }) {
  Vue.use(
    new VueSocketIO({
      debug: true,
      connection: $config.socketIOConnection,
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this variable will be available on the client-side, meaning anyone who loads your app can view it. If this is not a 'secret', then that's cool. If it is a secret, don't do this.